# Laravel Passport always say require username and password even the valid credentials are provided

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport

I am developing a REST API using Laravel. I am implementing authentication feature to my API using Passport. I am following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/@neo/getting-started-with-laravel-passport). I installed and configured successfully. The only issue I am having now is that when I request token from this endpoint "oauth/token", the API is always asking for username and password.

I registered a user in the database like this:

```
$user = [
      'name' => 'waiyanhein',
      'email' => 'iljimae.ic@gmail.com',
      'password' => bcrypt('testing')
   ];
   App\User::create($user);
```

The user is registered and a record is created in the database. Using the client id and secret which I got during the installation of password and user credentials, I made a request to generate the access token as in the tutorial. But I made the request from the REST Client. My request is as in the screenshot below:

[image]

As you can see, I provided the valid user credentials and client id and secret. When I made the request, the REST client tool prompt a pop up box requesting for the user credentials again as in the  screenshot below:

[image]

When I enter the credentials again, it keeps popping up the dialog box even if the credentials are valid. Instead of using username, I tried using email as well. Not matter how I tried, it is just asking for the user credentials. Why and what is wrong with the request? How can I correctly pass the credentials in the request?

Comment: Try sending the encrypted password, `bcrypt('testing')`.

Comment: I solved such problem by setting the primary key of the model to `name`. e.g. `protected $primaryKey = "name";` I hope this could help you.

Comment: Yes. That helped. But since "name" becomes PK, I did not like the solution. So, I am no longer using this Passport. :(. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel passport assumes that you have `username` column in the `users` table, since you don't have this columns but `name` instead, you need to tell passport about it.

**1st method [using Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):**

```
public function getUsernameAttribute(){
   return $this->attributes['name'];
 }
```

**2nd method using `findForPassport`:**

```
public function findForPassport($username) {
   return $this->where('name', $username)->first();
}
```

Comment: Adding an [accessor on the user model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for `getUsernameAttribute` would be a better approach.

Comment: i didn't try to use accessor for this, i did try `findForPassport`, but if this works, even better and less code

Comment: Doesn't require an additional db query and allows for reusing existing fields as the username, just thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: I tried passing name instead of username as well. Just did not work.

Comment: did you try both methods ?